# ValueError: Shapes (None, 128, 18) and (None, 128) are incompatible

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, keras

I'm having a problem with the shapes of my input to Keras/Tensorflow.

**EDIT** - I found that when I just specify 'accuracy' for my metrics it works fine and I can train my model, however when I do it the other way by adding precision, recall it fails with the error.

```
My Model summary is like this

Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding (Embedding)        (None, 128, 64)           2251520   
_________________________________________________________________
bidirectional (Bidirectional (None, 128, 128)          66048     
_________________________________________________________________
time_distributed (TimeDistri (None, 128, 18)           2322      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,319,890
Trainable params: 2,319,890
Non-trainable params: 0
```

I'm doing NER and padded my sentences to 128 words.

My Code is as follows and dataset is from [here](https://www.kaggle.com/abhinavwalia95/entity-annotated-corpus)

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold, KFold
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras import models

physical_devices = tf.config.list_physical_devices()
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[1], enable=True)

df = pd.read_csv("ner_dataset.csv", encoding="latin1")

# fill NaN - propogate non null values forward
df = df.fillna(method="ffill")

sent_count = len(set(df["Sentence #"].values))
print(sent_count)

words = list(set(df["Word"].values))
words_count = len(words)
print(words_count)

word2idx = {}
# add the padding and unknown token 
word2idx["PAD_TOKEN"] = len(word2idx)
word2idx["UNK_TOKEN"] = len(word2idx)

# add the rest
for i in range(0, len(words)):
    word2idx[words[i]] = len(word2idx)

# index to word mapping
idx2word = {i: w for w, i in word2idx.items()}

# number of unique tags
tags = list(set(df["Tag"].values))
tags_count = len(tags)
print(tags_count)


tag2idx = {}
tag2idx['PAD_TAG'] = 0 # this is the tag that is assigned to the pad tokens 'PAD_TOKEN'
for i in range(0, len(tags)):
    tag2idx[tags[i]] = len(tag2idx)
    
# index to tag mapping
idx2tag = {i: w for w, i in tag2idx.items()}

def getSentences(dataframe):
    
    sentences = []
    
    groups = dataframe.groupby("Sentence #")
    for name, group in groups:
        zipped = zip(group["Word"], group["Tag"])
        sentences.append(list(zipped))
        
    return sentences

sents = getSentences(df)

len(sents[0]), len(sents[1]) # sentences are of different lengths

max_len = 128

y = [[tag2idx[word[1]] for word in s] for s in sents]
y = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=y, value=tag2idx["PAD_TAG"], padding='post', truncating='post')

x = [[word2idx[word[0]] for word in s] for s in sents]
x = pad_sequences(maxlen=max_len, sequences=x, value=word2idx["PAD_TOKEN"], padding='post', truncating='post')


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

vocab_size = len(word2idx)
vocab_size

batch_size = 32


model = models.Sequential()


embeddinglayer = layers.Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size, output_dim=64, input_length=max_len)
model.add(embeddinglayer)

bilstm = layers.Bidirectional(layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True))
model.add(bilstm)

num_tags = len(tag2idx)
timedist = layers.TimeDistributed(layers.Dense(num_tags, activation="softmax"))
model.add(timedist)

model.summary()

METRICS = [
        'accuracy',
        tf.keras.metrics.Precision(name='precision'),
        tf.keras.metrics.Recall(name='recall')
    ]

model.compile(optimizer="adam",
              loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=METRICS)



history = model.fit(x_train, np.array(y_train), batch_size=batch_size, epochs=25, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=1)
```

The types after splitting are all np array

```
type(x_train), type(x_test), type(y_train), type(y_test)
(numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray, numpy.ndarray)
```

And the shapes are

```
((38367, 128), (9592, 128), (38367, 128), (9592, 128))
```

Each training item (sentence) is an array of word index of length 128, for example the x_train[0] looks like the array below (the y values are similar (same length 128) except they are index of the tags/labels for each word.)

```
array([25653,  1878, 26510, 12653, 33524, 15752, 30488, 14594, 33943,
        3656, 22478,   596, 13235, 10080, 16432, 18190, 20273, 10254,
       34463, 15526, 24899,  4359, 30488, 10525, 19165, 30439, 16205,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,     0,
           0,     0], dtype=int32)
```

EDIT: Error Below

```
Epoch 1/25
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-35a0fcfc79ab> in <module>
    111 
    112 
--> 113 history = model.fit(x_train, np.array(y_train), batch_size=batch_size, epochs=25, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), verbose=1)

c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1098                 _r=1):
   1099               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1100               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1101               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1102                 context.async_wait()

c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    826     tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()
    827     with trace.Trace(self._name) as tm:
--> 828       result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    829       compiler = "xla" if self._experimental_compile else "nonXla"
    830       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    869       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    870       initializers = []
--> 871       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    872     finally:
    873       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    724     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    725         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 726             *args, **kwds))
    727 
    728     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2967       args, kwargs = None, None
   2968     with self._lock:
-> 2969       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2970     return graph_function
   2971 

c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3359 
   3360           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3361           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3362           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3363 

c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3204             arg_names=arg_names,
   3205             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3206             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3207         self._function_attributes,
   3208         function_spec=self.function_spec,

c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    988         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    989 
--> 990       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    991 
    992       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    632             xla_context.Exit()
    633         else:
--> 634           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    635         return out
    636 

c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    975           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    976             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 977               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    978             else:
    979               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:805 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:795 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:788 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:758 train_step
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:408 update_state
        metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
    c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py:90 decorated
        update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
    c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py:177 update_state_fn
        return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
    c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\metrics.py:1291 update_state  **
        sample_weight=sample_weight)
    c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\metrics_utils.py:354 update_confusion_matrix_variables
        y_pred.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(y_true.shape)
    c:\miniconda3\envs\ner\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py:1134 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 128, 18) and (None, 128) are incompatible
```

Comment: Please also mention the line number at which you are getting the error, a short stack trace would be better

Comment: What do you exactly mean by '**I think it was working** in tensorflow 2.2.0 but then I recently upgraded to 2.4.0 and it broke.'?

Comment: @Courage added complete stack trace

Comment: @krenerd I recently upgraded my cuda to 11 and tensorflow to 2.4, my code was working prior to that, I'll have to try this on a different computer with tensorflow 2.2 to verify, will post back to let you know the result

Comment: @erotavlas If you want to run in a downgraded version of tensorflow, just downgrade your version by `pip install tensorflow==2.2.x` or use a virtual env.

Comment: @krenerd ok never mind my previous comment about version (i removed it from the post), I tried it in another environment with 2.2.0 and it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your `x`, `y` arguments to `model.fit()` are inconsistent: `x` is a list, `y` -s a numpy array. Try:

```
history = model.fit(np_array(x_train), np.array(y_train))
```

Comment: I found the problem (see my edit at stop of post)  it has to do with the metrics I added in addition to accuracy, precision and recall and thats what caused it to break.  Not sure why this would happen though.

Comment: I just realized maybe it has to do with this task being a multiclass classification, because I was able to use all three metrics when doing binary classification for images.  Maybe those metrics can't be used for this problem?